# Does the Document Checklist issued by gov.uk need to be uploaded on VFS global along with other supporting documents?

Tags: visas, uk, vfs-global

On the vfs page for self upload of documents, the option "document checklist" was part of the additional document section. However there are clear instructions on the gov.uk document checklist to bring the unsigned checklist to the biometric appointment and sign it there. In that case, what am I supposed to upload? The unsigned filled up checklist or the unfilled pdf as downloaded from gov.uk? [image]

Also, does the cover letter go in additional documents?